# UINavigationcontroller mixing up uiviewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationcontroller` connected to a `UIViewcontroller` and then two more `UIViewcontrollers` connected through a push segue (connected to the first UIViewcontroller).

I also have a `UILongPressGuestureRecognizer` that gets activated when the user long presses the navigation bar at the top of the view. This gesture brings up an action sheet that provides settings for the user.

My problem occurs after I use the action sheet to push to one of the seconds view. 
When I swipe left to go back to the original controller the phone still thinks I'm on that second view. When I press and hold the navigation bar it crashes because I don't have any code supporting it in the second view.

Why does it happen?

Comment: So basically what you want is to back to the previous controller from where you came, is it ?

Comment: How about add some code or a sample project to Github?

Comment: My set up is Navigation Controller - > ViewController -PUSH Segue-> ViewController.  Both View Controllers have a tableview on them. Problem:(only occurs after i swipe back from the second view controller to the first) If i click a button on the first view controller to refresh the uitableview, it refreshes the uitableview in the 2nd View controller. WHY?